# Forcing adverts via apache configuration file

Tags: php, htaccess, apache2, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a server I am trying to force adverts for free users.  I can do it with a .htaccess file with this line "php_value auto_append_file '/var/www/vhosts/demoblog/demoblog.tk/httpdocs/test_ad.php'" but when I try to add it to the virtualHost it does nothing.  I cannot see anything in the apache error log, and yes I do restart apache.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `php_value` directive you must be running PHP in Apache as a module. You also need to set `AllowOverride Options` and `AllowOverride All`, otherwise the directive will be ignored.

See [How to change configuration settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).